# Custom font is working on XML preview but not working on RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, custom-font

Code for `TextView` with custom font declared on `style="@style/SbTextView.ListTitle"`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/symbolCompany"
    style="@style/SbTextView.ListTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:typeface="normal"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    tools:text="@sample/watchlist_companies.json/data/symbol" />
```

Style using custom font `@font/sb_proxima` with **BOLD** `textStyle`:

```
<style name="SbTextView.ListTitle" parent="SbTextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sb_proxima</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_body</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/contentcolor</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.15</item>
</style>
```

Style parent `SbTextView`

```
<style name="SbTextView" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance"/>
```

Font family `@font/sb_proxima`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        android:font="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"

        app:font="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"/>

    <font
        android:font="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"

        app:font="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"/>

</font-family>
```

What rendered on design preview (on XML) look like the following picture

XML Preview

[image: XML Preview]

On runtime inside `RecyclerView` look like rendered on RecylerView

[image: Rendered on RecylerView]

Comment: did you added Bold ttf too?

Comment: Yes, I have two fonts. Bold and Regular one.

Comment: try to use font file name without underscore ( _ ) character.

Comment: @RahulKhurana But in Official docs, the font file name seem not a problem. Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: ok. try to add textStyle bold in TextView not in Style. let me know if it make any difference

Comment: Already tried so, but no luck

Answer (score 2):

in your **@font/sb_proxima** file, you need to define bold font like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<font
    android:font="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"

    app:font="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400"/>

<font
    android:font="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"

    app:font="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400"/>
<font
    android:font="@font/proxima_nova_bold"
    android:fontStyle="bold"
    android:fontWeight="400"

    app:font="@font/proxima_nova_bold"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400"/>

</font-family>
```

Also, don't forget to include **proxima_nova_bold** file.

**EDIT**

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource) they mentioned:

> android:fontWeight
>   Integer. The weight of the font. This attribute is used when the font is loaded into the font stack and overrides any weight information in the font's header tables. The attribute value must be a positive number, a multiple of 100, and between 100 and 900, inclusive. If you do not specify the attribute, the app uses the value from the font's header tables.The most common values are 400 for regular weight and 700 for bold weight.

In your font file you have mentioned font weight as 400 which is commonly used for regular. Try with 700 font weight.

Comment: `android:fontStyle' only have option ["normal" | "italic"]. Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource. Btw, I also noticed that my style worked on regular XML layout but not on RecylerView item.

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompatTextView instead of TextView

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/symbolCompany"
    style="@style/SbTextView.ListTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:typeface="normal"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    tools:text="@sample/watchlist_companies.json/data/symbol" />
```